React Oauth Google not visible on mobile devices
I'm using @react-oauth/google to implement One Tap on the site. I am particularly not using google login. Rather have a separate login module and have integrated One Tap and using the credential for internal login.
While this works when the page is viewed on desktop, there is an issue on mobile devices.
On a few mobile devices, the pop up is not displayed while it's working fine on others.
I checked for the privacy settings for third party cookies and chrome login, and still the pop up is not visible.
This is how I have added the hook.
useGoogleOneTapLogin({
  onSuccess: credentialResponse => {
    if (credentialResponse.credential) {
    
    } else {
      console.log('Unable to receive credential');
    }
  },
  onError: () => {
    console.log('Google one tap Login Failed');
  },
  cancel_on_tap_outside: true,
  disabled: hideShowGooglePrompt(),
  promptMomentNotification: (notifications) => {
  
  }
});

I checked the documentation and there is no mention of specific versions of android or chrome.
In the disabled field, I'm passing a function which returns a value after a 5 second delay to show the pop with the current login state of the site.
The package version is 0.12.1

onError(e), log the error e.message. Any errors on the console?

Nope. No error. The pop up just doesn't show up.

I don't think I will be able to answer your question. However, some general feedback, in case there's no response from others: The question  misses  [mcve]: 1. Which  mobile device and 2. Which browser in that device? 3. A complete minimal code, which can be used to reproduce the problem. If you add these 3, it might attract more users to look into the issue.

There is no specific list of devices as the behaviour is too random. Specifically, it's the chrome browser. As per the documentation, https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-oauth/google, the provider is added to the root level and the above hook is added in a particular component.

If you don't get any error, the popup doesn't open and it isn't your browser's popup blocker, then the function that's meant to open the popup is not being invoked.

Got it resolved after removing the customizations on the disbaled key.
